# Wordpress: How can I group posts without using categories or tags?

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a dynamic dictionary with Wordpress a la http://urbandictionary.com/. The functionality I want to emulate is having multiple definitions for a single word. I need each of these definitions to be able to be rated by the user (currently using wp-postratings, but I'm open to any other plugin). The idea is that the users determine the most accurate definition of the word via this post ratings system.

Currently I have each definition as an individual post with the same title, e.g., definition #1 for "dog" and definition #2 for "dog" are separate posts with the title "dog." **Here's where I'm running into trouble:** I don't want the user to be aware of the structural distinction between the different definitions. In other words, I don't want there to be 2 separate pages—I want the user to think, for all intents and purposes, that there is  a singular page that contains all of the word's definitions.

This is similar to what categories do, obviously, but I'm already categorizing the words by their content. I'm looking for a more explicit connection between the posts. (I also would prefer not to have 500+ categories.)

Would it be easier to input secondary definitions as custom field values, rather than as separate posts? My only worry is that no plugin to my knowledge allows the user to rate anything other than singular posts in their entirety.

Does anyone have an idea how I can set this up? I've searched for days and haven't found an applicable solution. Any help would be much appreciated. Hopefully this makes sense. It was a difficult problem for me to articulate.

**TL;DR: Can I create, using custom fields or a plugin or whatever else, a more explicit connection between posts than by categories or tags?**

Comment: Just a thought - but how about using the comments functionality of WordPress and having user be able to vote those? Create a custom post type that's literally stripped down to just the title (word) and have the comments functionality handle the rest. By all means slate me if this is a bad suggestion :)

Comment: I really like that idea, Joe. I'll have to tinker around with it. I'm worried that having the definitions as comments will limit what I can do with them (social media share buttons, etc.) Very creative, though.

Comment: By coincidence, I read this question yesterday, and today was looking at the [Literary](http://themeforest.net/item/literary-a-wordpress-blog-theme-with-a-twist/full_screen_preview/4713129) WordPress theme. That theme has a shortcode for blockquotes that allows each quote to get a star rating -- thought that was worth mentioning, as a post per word with each definition as a shortcode that includes a rating might be a possible approach for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with Joe Buckle's idea, making each definition a comment. I styled the comments template to match exactly what I was going for. Bit of a workaround but it gets the job done. Thanks.